Getting error with react after updating eslint to V9.0.0
I have recently updated my eslint version in create-react-app project. Previously I was using eslint V7.24 and I was using .eslintrc.js file but after updating to eslint v9.0.0 I started getting error that old format is not supported so I created new eslint.config.js file to migrate from V8 to V9 and also updated other required packages. I have migrated most of the code but now when I am running npm run lint, I am getting below mentioned error. I am sharing my devDependancies from package.json file and eslint.config.js file code here. Please let me know what am I missing here.
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.0.0

TypeError: Key "rules": Key "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": Could not find "jsx-closing-bracket-location" in plugin "react".
    at throwRuleNotFoundError (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/rule-validator.js:66:11)
    at RuleValidator.validate (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/rule-validator.js:147:17)
    at [finalizeConfig] (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/flat-config-array.js:211:23)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfig (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:1022:55)
    at FlatConfigArray.isFileIgnored (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:1046:15)
    at /Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:322:49
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at entryFilter (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:309:28)
    at Object.isAppliedFilter (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/readers/common.js:12:31)
    at AsyncReader._handleEntry (/Users/Pradhumn_Sharma/Projects/impro-fe/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/readers/async.js:86:20)

"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "~7.24.1",
        "@eslint/js": "^9.0.0",
        "@testing-library/dom": "~9.3.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "~6.4.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "~14.2.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "~14.5.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~7.5.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~7.5.0",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "eslint": "~9.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "~9.1.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "~7.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.29.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "~28.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "~48.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsonc": "~2.15.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "~5.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "~7.34.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "~4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "~1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-spellcheck": "0.0.20",
        "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "~6.2.0",
        "fake-indexeddb": "5.0.1",
        "globals": "^15.0.0",
        "pre-commit": "~1.2.2",
        "prettier": "~3.2.5",
        "prettier-eslint": "~16.3.0",
        "prettier-eslint-cli": "~8.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "~5.0.1",
        "sass": "~1.74.1",
        "stylelint": "~16.3.1",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "~9.0.5",
        "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "~13.1.0",
        "stylelint-prettier": "~5.0.0",
        "stylelint-scss": "~6.2.1"
    }

**ESLINT CODE FROM eslint.config.js**

import babelParser from "@babel/eslint-parser";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import importConfig from "eslint-plugin-import";
import jest from "eslint-plugin-jest";
import jsdocConfig from "eslint-plugin-jsdoc";
import jsoncConfig from "eslint-plugin-jsonc";
import reactHooks from "eslint-plugin-react-hooks";
import pluginReactAllConfig from "eslint-plugin-react/configs/all.js";
import pluginReactConfig from "eslint-plugin-react/configs/recommended.js";
import sortKeysFixConfig from "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix";
import spellcheck from "eslint-plugin-spellcheck";
import globals from "globals";

// export default [
//   {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
//   pluginJs.configs.recommended,
//   pluginReactConfig,
// ];

export default [
    pluginJs.configs.recommended,
    {
        files: ["**/*.{js,jsx}"],
        ...jest.configs["flat/recommended"],
        plugins: {
            react: { ...pluginReactAllConfig, ...pluginReactConfig },
            jest,
            import: importConfig,
            jsdoc: jsdocConfig,
            jsonc: jsoncConfig,
            "react-hooks": reactHooks,
            "sort-keys-fix": sortKeysFixConfig,
            spellcheck: spellcheck
        },
        languageOptions: {
            parser: babelParser,
            parserOptions: {
                requireConfigFile: false,
                babelOptions: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    configFile: false,
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
                },
                ecmaFeatures: {
                    jsx: true
                }
            },
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.node,
                it: "readonly",
                jest: "readonly",
                test: "readonly",
                expect: "readonly",
                indexedDB: "readonly",
                describe: "readonly"
            }
        },
        settings: { react: { version: "detect" } },
        rules: {
            "array-bracket-newline": ["error", "consistent"],
            "array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "never"],
            "array-callback-return": "error",
            "array-element-newline": [
                "error",
                {
                    "ArrayExpression": "consistent",
                    "ArrayPattern": { "minItems": 3 }
                }
            ],
            "arrow-spacing": "error",
            "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs"],
            "camelcase": ["error", { "ignoreDestructuring": true, "properties": "never" }],
            "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
            "comma-spacing": [
                "error",
                {
                    "after": true,
                    "before": false
                }
            ],
            "curly": ["error", "all"],
            "default-case": "off",
            "eqeqeq": ["error", "always"],
            "func-call-spacing": ["error", "never"],
            "function-call-argument-newline": ["error", "consistent"],
            "import/first": "off",
            "import/order": ["error", { "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index"] }],
            "indent": ["error", 4, { "SwitchCase": 1, "ignoredNodes": ["ConditionalExpression"] }],
            "jest/no-mocks-import": "off",
            "jsdoc/newline-after-description": 0, // Required for vs code auto formatting
            "jsdoc/require-hyphen-before-param-description": 1,
            "jsdoc/require-jsdoc": [
                "error",
                {
                    "require": {
                        "ArrowFunctionExpression": true,
                        "ClassExpression": true,
                        "FunctionDeclaration": true,
                        "FunctionExpression": true,
                        "MethodDefinition": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "jsonc/sort-keys": "error",
            "keyword-spacing": ["error", { "after": true, "before": true }],
            "max-len": [
                "error",
                {
                    "code": 120,
                    "ignorePattern": '".*": ".*"' // Ignore pattern for strings in json as they can't be broken in multi lines
                }
            ],
            "no-console": "error",
            "no-dupe-else-if": "error",
            "no-extend-native": "off",
            "no-nested-ternary": "error",
            "no-useless-escape": "off",
            "no-var": "error",
            "object-curly-newline": ["error", { "consistent": true, "multiline": true }],
            "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
            "object-property-newline": ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true }],
            "padding-line-between-statements": [
                "error",
                // Always one empty line before return statement
                {
                    "blankLine": "always",
                    "next": "return",
                    "prev": "*"
                },
                // Always one empty line between methods
                {
                    "blankLine": "always",
                    "next": ["block-like", "multiline-block-like"],
                    "prev": ["block-like", "multiline-block-like"]
                },
                // Avoids more than one empty line
                {
                    "blankLine": "never",
                    "next": "empty",
                    "prev": "empty"
                }
            ],
            "prefer-const": "error",
            "quote-props": ["error", "always"],
            "quotes": ["error", "double"],
            "radix": "off",
            "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error",
            "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
            // "react/jsx-boolean-value": ["warn", "always"],
            "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": "error",
            "react/jsx-closing-tag-location": "error",
            "react/jsx-curly-brace-presence": [
                "error",
                {
                    "children": "ignore",
                    "props": "always"
                }
            ],
            "react/jsx-tag-spacing": ["error", { "beforeSelfClosing": "always" }],
            "react/no-multi-comp": ["error", { "ignoreStateless": true }],
            "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
            "semi": ["error", "always"],
            "sort-keys": [
                "error",
                "asc",
                {
                    "caseSensitive": true,
                    "minKeys": 2,
                    "natural": false
                }
            ],
            "sort-keys-fix/sort-keys-fix": "error",
            "space-before-blocks": "error",
            "space-infix-ops": ["error", { "int32Hint": false }],
            "spellcheck/spell-checker": [
                "error",
                {
                    "minLength": 4,
                    "skipWords": [
                 
                        "datasource",
                        "apis"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            // Added this so test file don't give error when accessing dom element using DOM api
            "testing-library/no-node-access": "off"
        }
    }
];




The plugin eslint-plugin-react is not compatible with eslint V9 yet - see here.
In the last comment of the linked issue, the maintainer states "new eslint majors always take months before everything supports them, and this one will take longer" - so maybe the best way to solve your problem would be to just wait until all plugins will be upgraded to be compatible with the new eslint version.

Just to add more info: I also tried to migrate to ESLint v9, and it didn't work. Too many breaking changes. I downgraded to ESLint v8.57.0, that's the sweet spot as of now.
